# Mulch + raised garden for a desert water saving Vegetable Garden?

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, mulch, water, desert

I am planning a raised bed vegetable garden in dry Southern California. I wish to produce food in my dry climate, and am concerned for possible future water restrictions. Besides the water savings from a raised bed garden, I understand that a layer of mulch can prevent water evaporation as well. Has anyone had luck with a vegetable garden in a raised bed garden with much, such as I am planning?

Comment: Have you seen this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rPPUmStKQ4

Comment: Do people really do raised beds in arid climates? I live in the UK, and we do raised beds to help with drainage from all the rain for plants that like drier soil... what kind of raised bed? when you say 'weed block' do you just mean thick mulch, not weed membrane?